# Lorentz vs Einstein

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, history

(1)
Lorentz believed in the aether which is known for being the place that all velocities should be measured with respect to,  Did lorentz believe that the speed of light is invariant to all observer's?

As  he developed "the transformation under which Maxwell's equations are invariant when transformed from the aether to a moving frame"

So measuring a velocity not with respect to the aether should stil give correct results, or did his aether theory still have to give V measures with respect to the aether

(2)

Lorentz first came up with the correct coordinate transformation that is consistent with maxwells equations. The property of such transformation shows that the speed of light is invariant.

So why is einstein credited with time dialation/ length contraction? When it was lorentz that first proposed the correct transformation? Aether or not.

Comment: This is an interesting read (along with the references therein): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_priority_dispute

Comment: You certainly heard of **Lorentz** contraction, **Lorentz** transformation, **Lorentz** invariance/covariance, **Lorentz** scalar, etc...?

Answer (score 1):

Einstein came up with the correct set of postulates and framework (all inertial reference frames are indistinguishable, speed of light is invariant, two-way speed of light convention for measuring time and distances) that made all known experimental observations on time dilation, stellar aberration, etc fall out naturally from the math in a simple form, without ad hoc concepts like aether.  His results also showed how to transform Maxwell's equations from a moving to a stationary reference frame.  It's true that Lorentz had already derived the transformation equations, which Eistein credits him with in the paper.